# C# Not checking all Username and Passwords

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

The User Puts in Username and Password. When it runs goes through and reads the text file and checks if the username and password match if they do it says welcome. The things is when i type in the first Username and Password ( Green and 123) it logs in but when i type in (Blue 123) nothing happens. Is it not reading the whole text?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace BookStoreOnline
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] Val = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\......\......\...\.....\...\Login.txt");

            for (int i = 0; i < Val.Length/2; i += 2)
            {
                if (TextBox1.Text == Val[i])
                {
                    if (TextBox2.Text == Val[i + 1])
                    {                      
                        Session.Add("UserName", Val[i]);
                        string x = "HomePage";
                        Response.Redirect(x + ".aspx");
                    }

                    else
                        Label1.Text = "Incorrect Password.";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The text file looks likes this ( could it be my text file format is wrong) ?

```
Green
123

Blue
123
```

Comment: BTW consider taking the `else` out of the `for` loop as it's useless there.

Comment: will do still work in progress :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the culprit:

`i < Val.Length/2`

It is checking half lines of text file not all lines, so it should be:

`i < Val.Length`

Now it will loop through all lines of it.

### Update:

I have refactored little your code block

Change your code to like this:

```
bool LoggedIn= false;
string x = null;
for (int i = 0; i < Val.Length/2; i += 2)
{
    if (TextBox1.Text == Val[i])
    {
        if (TextBox2.Text == Val[i + 1])
        {

            Session.Add("UserName", Val[i]);
            x = "HomePage";
            LoggedIn = true;
            break;
         }
         else
            LoggedIn = false;

    }


}
if(LoggedIn)
  Response.Redirect(x + ".aspx");
else
  Label1.Text = "Incorrect Password.";
```

Comment: actually i thought is was that to but its not when i click the button it does nothing but when i type in green logs in but when type in blue still does nothing

Comment: Thanks i will check i did it at school worked perfectly and when i tried opening it up in visual studios IDK what happened lol

Comment: @NBera problem is you are not breaking loop when match found , it iterates again and creates problem see my edited post